# Flash Builder Long Press on List - Mobile

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, list, mobile, flash-builder

I want to display a list (in a tile layout, but I don't think that changes anything) and open up the editing window for the tile that I long press on (i.e. press for at least 1 second). The timer starts fine and the longPressHandler event is correctly called after 1 second, however, the object that is selected is the previous object that I had touched.

For example, say I tap on Object A, then I long press on Object B: the longPressHandler will "open" up Object A in the editing window. I have debugged and I see that the SelectedItem property of my List only updates after I end my long press (as in, after I pick up my finger or release the mouse button). Is there any way to open up the currently selected item?

---

Relevant Actionscript:

```
private  var longPressTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000,1);

private function startLongPressMouse(event:MouseEvent):void {   
    startLongPressTimer();
    list.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, endLongPressMouse);
}
private function endLongPressMouse(event:MouseEvent):void {
    stopLongPressTimer();
    enableClick();
    list.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, endLongPressMouse);
}
private function startLongPress(event:TouchEvent):void {
    startLongPressTimer();
    list.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_MOVE, endLongPress);
}
private function endLongPress(event:TouchEvent):void {
    stopLongPressTimer();
    enableClick();
    list.removeEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_MOVE, endLongPress);
}
private function startLongPressTimer():void {
    longPressTimer.start();
    longPressTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, longPressHandler);
}
protected function disableClick():void {
    trace("disable click");
    list.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, regularClickHander);
}
public function enableClick():void {
    list.callLater(list.addEventListener, [MouseEvent.CLICK, regularClickHander]);
}
public function resetListSelection():void {
    list.selectedIndex = -1;
    list.validateDisplayList();
}
private function stopLongPressTimer():void{
    longPressTimer.stop();
    longPressTimer.reset()
}
public function longPressHandler(event:TimerEvent):void{
    disableClick();
    stopLongPressTimer();
    lblD.text = "Long Press Detected on: " + list.selectedItem.className;
}
```

---

Relevant MXML:

```
 <s:List id="list"  dataProvider="{grades}" touchBegin="startLongPress(event)" touchEnd="endLongPress(event)"
        mouseDown="startLongPressMouse(event)" mouseUp="endLongPressMouse(event)"
        labelField="name"
        left.landscape="10" right.landscape="20" top.landscape="350" bottom.landscape="20"
        left.portrait="20" right.portrait="20" top.portrait="350" bottom.portrait="20">
    <s:itemRenderer>
        <fx:Component>
            <s:ItemRenderer width="100%" height="200">

                <s:Label text="{data.className}" top="30" horizontalCenter="0" color="#646464"/>
                <s:Label text="{data.credits}" top="50" horizontalCenter="0" color="#646464" fontSize="14"/>
                <s:Label text="{data.grade}" top="100" horizontalCenter="0" color="#646464" fontSize="14"/>
            </s:ItemRenderer>
        </fx:Component>
    </s:itemRenderer>
    <s:layout>
        <s:TileLayout requestedColumnCount="3" requestedColumnCount.landscape="4" columnAlign="justifyUsingWidth"/>
    </s:layout>
</s:List>
```

---

I changed the longPressHandler to just display the name of the selected item rather than open up the editing window.

Let me know if you need any more information. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: +1 for a detailed question. It may take some experimentation; but I think you can save the access the 'hovered' renderer in the mouseDown event and store it for later access.  Look at the "target".  Alternatively, you may have to bubble your own events up from the renderer.

Comment: The problem with the "hovered" renderer is that I am making this app for mobile devices so there will be no mouse. I only have the mouse event handlers for testing. I will look into making custom events. Thank you for your input!

Comment: In Flex on mobile; the mouse events should fire alongside the touch events.  mouse_Move is probably not the right one; but mouseDown and MouseUp should be akin to TouchStart and TouchEnd [I may be wrong about the last one].  But, in my own experience any testing of a mobile app that isn't on a mobile device is a waste of time.

Comment: I meant that there is no hover event for touch, only for mouse. I tried TouchEnd before, and retested it just now, but the same issue is present.

Comment: Is there a way to manually update the list.selectedItem property on touchBegin?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create a custom event (with custom property) so that you can pass whatever data you want when you dispatch the event.

```
package events;
{
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class YourCustomEvent extends Event
    {
        public var yourData:Object;

        public function YourCustomEvent(type:String, yourData:Object)
        {
            super(type);
            this.yourData = yourData;
        }

        override public function clone():Event{
            return new YourCustomEvent(type, yourData);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

PS: I wanted to put this in the comment but it got bigger as a typed :)